# Laravel 8 Google and Facebook login through socialite error in callback URL. error too many redirects

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-socialite

I'm new in this community and also I'm a newbie in Laravel 8. I've implemented socialite login for Facebook and Google and I want to implement a method where if the user doesn't exist in my database through login with Facebook or Google it saves the user name and email from social sites on my database and `registration type = social login` provider. but I am stuck in the callback URL when I click on continue with google id it redirects me and shows me the error page can't be displayed. Sorry for my bad English here is my callback URL method.

```
public function HandleFacebookCallback(){
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->Customer();
        $customermail = CustomerEmail::where('email','=',$data->email)->first();
        if(!$customer){
            $customer = new Customer();
            $customermail = new CustomerEmail();
            $customer->contact_person = $data->name;
            $customermail->email = $data->email;
            $customer->type = 'Primary';
            $customer->registration_type = 'Facebook';
            $customer->save();
            $customermail->save();
        }
    }
```

I have 2 tables for customers where I want to insert the data after the user login.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please show the error message you got. It will help in better understanding of the issue you are facing and In your code you have created a user, after successful creation of user, you should provide a redirect page.

Comment: thank you for your response. Actually this issue has been resolved I convert my localhost into domain.local so facebook login issue has been resolved but now google restrict the url only FQDN allow in google Oauth login